# I need feed aggregator, built on small-footprint high-performance programming language web framework (need suggestion)

Tags: programming-languages, web-frameworks, ping, aggregation

I have different contents sitting on different subdomain, each on different framework and different database.

The feed aggregator purpose is for:

1. aggregate contents from the
   subdomain,
2. store data for 1 week, in fast embedded database
3. generate RSS
4. ping to `ping-o-matic` and some
   others

(thats why I want the aggregator built on web framework; for easier extensibility). The RSS is for additional statistics.

Currently I achieved this using PHP with sqlite3, but I'm looking for other (higher performance, lower footprint) programming language, hope they can performs even better for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you worked it with PHP i think the best would be to use Python. It's dynamic typed like PHP but is faster (and better in many other factors, for me at least).

Anyway, there are lots of agregators and "crawlers" out there.

You could use the [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) plataform (with Solr, Nutch).

Take a look at it.